# creating a word document using lotusscript

Tags: lotusscript

I have been looking at all types of examples but haven't been able to find something that shows me how to take a Notes document and create a microsoft word document from the detail of the Notes document.

I am wanting to write this in LotusScript so that if our users are needing to send the document to the outside person, they can send it via Word format.

Any url's that can give me an example of this is greatly appreciated.  I have created excel documents and have formatted them but not versed on creating word document in lotusscript. 
We are running version 7.0.3 through 8.0.3.

Your comments much appreciated.

Jean

Comment: There are many ways. How did you create Excel sheets from LotusScript? You could proceed the same way.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example for creating a Word document from scratch and create and fill a table with Notes data: [Integrating IBM Lotus Notes with Microsoft Office using LotusScript and automation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/notes-ole/#icomments).

If you want to put data at Word bookmarks you can find out about it here: [HowTo: Create a Word Document from LotusScript](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/HowTo_Create_a_Word_Document_from_LotusScript).

In case you want to convert whole Notes documents into Word documents (RTF) this could be a solution: [Convert Lotus Notes Documents to PDFs with LotusScript and Microsoft Word](http://www.reisinger.ws/2013/07/12/convert-lotus-notes-documents-to-pdfs-with-lotusscript-and-microsoft-word/)